# Insert new pair at index 0 to map. ( Dart )

Tags: dart

I'm to loop this map. So I would like to be able to insert a pair into this map. How do I do it?

```
  Map<String, String> fruits = {'Apple': 'Golden', 'Orange': 'Orange'};

  fruits.insert(0, {'Grape': 'Green'}); // doesn't work

  print(fruits); //{Grape: Green, Apple: Golden, Orange: Orange}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the default implementation of a `Map` is a [LinkedHashMap](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap-class.html), which preserves the inserting order, you should be able to use this syntax to insert an element either at the start or at the end of a map.

```
  Map<String, String> fruits = {'Apple': 'Golden', 'Orange': 'Orange'};

  fruits = {'Grape': 'Green', ...fruits};
    
  print(fruits); //{Grape: Green, Apple: Golden, Orange: Orange}
```

Be aware that you are actually creating a new Map rather then inserting the element in the existing one.

Answer (score 2):

Map entries do not have numeric indices (Unless you're working with `Map<int, T>` of course), and there is no Map.insert method. Instead, the way to add a pair to a map is to assign a value to a key, like so:

```
fruits['Grape'] = 'Green';
```

For some additional info, Map is unordered, meaning there is no index 0 - **BUT**, if you really must have an ordered set of keys and values, you can use `List<MapEntry>`:

```
List<MapEntry<String, String>> fruits = [
  MapEntry('Apple', 'Golden'), 
  MapEntry('Orange', 'Orange')
];

fruits.insert(0, MapEntry('Grape', 'Green'));

print(fruits); // [MapEntry(Grape: Green), MapEntry(Apple: Golden), MapEntry(Orange: Orange)]
```

**Even better though**, you might consider using a Fruit class, then having a `List<Fruit>`:

```
class Fruit {
  final String name;
  final String color;

  Fruit(this.name, this.color});
}
```

Then:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = [
  Fruit('Apple', 'Golden'), 
  Fruit('Orange', 'Orange')
];

fruits.insert(0, Fruit('Grape', 'Green'));

print(fruits);
```